# Security: how to allow an application (grim) to be launched only from an interactive shell?

Tags: linux, security, wayland, apparmor

My need is the following: I would like to allow an application (grim) to be launched only from an interactive shell, but not from another application, especially a script shell...

- In principle, is this possible with AppArmor?
- Rather than an interactive shell, wouldn't it be better to use a specific "unlock/startup" application that takes care of launching the application passed as a parameter?
- What could be the workaround for a malicious application? Can it cascade start an interactive shell, which in turn launches the application I want to protect?

grim - grab images from a Wayland compositor

Thanks,

grim allows to make screenshots under Wayland. I would like to use it from Sway. But how sure can I be that no malicious application can also use it for its own purposes?

Comment: Obviously, if the malicious application embeds the "grim" code then it's all over, and the whole security aspect of Wayland is compromised! So, how can this problem be handled by the Wayland compositor?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.